# IBM Liberty : It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a non transacted session

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, mq

I am migrating a WAS6 application to Liberty profile.
In my project I have a section which is not under global transaction and there I read a message from one queue and drop it into another.

For that I use a transacted queue session and at end of all I do a commit method call and for all exceptions I do a rollback.

Queue session:

```
QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Exception:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegelStateException:JMSCC0014:It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a nontransacted session
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessoImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NSLServices.createException(NSLServices.java)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NSLServices.createException(NSLServices.java)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.commit(JmsSessionImpl.java)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.commit(MQSession.java)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.SessionWrapper.commit(SessionWrapper.java)
at .....my package....JMSHelper.commit(JMSHelper.java)
at .......my code..........(myclass.java)
at ..............mycode............................
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor$ListenerWrapper.handleNotification(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$SendNotifJob.run(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1.execute(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java)
at javax.management.timer.Timer.sendNotification(Timer.java)
at javax.management.timer.TimernotifyAlarmClock(Timer.java)
at javax.management.timer.TimerAlarmClock.run(Timer.java)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java)
JMSCC0014:It is not valid to call the 'rollback' method on a nontransacted session
```

QCF settings

```
<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="..\path\wmq.jmsra.rar">

<jmsQueueConnectionFactory id="qcfId" jndiName="jms/myQCF" >
  <properties.wmqJms channel="mychannel" hostName="myhost" port="1234" queueManager="myQManager" />
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
```

Could you please advise.

Comment: Are you using the MQ adapter supported in Liberty?  (E.g. following instructions like [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633761) and [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/samples-WebSphere_MQ_JMS_Messaging_on_Liberty).) If so, maybe post your server.xml.

Comment: Can you provide the configuration for the Connection Factory you are using?

Comment: @Alasdair : I have modified the question with a sample connection factory I am using.